# VS2010: installing some themes for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, themes

I am working as a team member and use Visual Studio 2010. The Source control which we all use is TFS.

Can I install some themes of VS while others don't install them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an excellent extension available at http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378/

The selected theme applies to your system only. All extensions you install, will not appear on other systems. 
These extensions are not part of your projects/code and will never be checked in into TFS.